# how to change style of table row depending on cell timestamp value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that contains a date column. This column has dates from the past to the future including the current time with intervals of approximately 7 min (it may change).
I need to color the row which has present value with green and to move green to the next row when the next time is reached.
Is it possible to listen to the time value and change style over the rows?
I could color the present value but when time goes on, the style doesn't move to the next row since the code executed once on the page load.

Here is my code attempt:
I am using vue so in the HTML table part:

```html
<tbody v-for='row in rows' :key='row.id'>
  <tr :style="{'background-color': dateFormat(row.date) ?'green' :'' }">
    ...
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and in the methods:

```js
dateFormat(d) {
  const time = new Date(d);
  const cc = new Date();
  if (time.getMinutes() === cc.getMinutes()) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your attempt code?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout , and if you get stuck when trying to resolve your task, then ask a question.

Comment: I have added my code attempt @StackSlave

Comment: You would need some kind of test on the time. Perhaps within `setInterval` or on some kind of Event.

Comment: @StackSlave that is exactly what I am looking for. the event that listens to cell value!

Comment: `setInterval` will fail if the interval varies between each tow rows! @Teemu

Comment: I didn't suggest you to use `setInterval`. Providing the table is static, read the values of the date cells to a JS array, then iterate the array to find the first date which is later than the current date, the previous cell has the current date. Then calculate the difference between the current and the next date, and set a timed function (`setTimeout`), which executes after the calculated difference. In that function, reset the style of the current row, set new current and set its style, and calculate the new delay based on the current and the next date. Finally set a new timer.

Comment: No, you use `setInterval` to test your time. Use `Element.classList.add('classNameHere')` to add an HTML class attribute, and `Element.classList.remove('classNameHere')` to remove an HTML class. Prewrite your CSS class to style how you want.

Comment: @StackSlave An interval is overkilling because the points of the time when to change the background are known.

Comment: @Teemu, how would you know when you've hit those points of time?

Comment: @StackSlave OP said the dates are in the table cells, it's trivial to calculate the delay and set a timeout to fire after the delay, you don't have to check the time in an interval.

Comment: @Teemu, that makes sense. `setTimeout(()=>{}, otherMillisecondTimestamp-Date.now());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not too much information of what kind of a table you want to integrate the action to. You can apply the following instructions to achieve what you want.

Make a "model" of the task, at first, read the dates when the active row should change to a JS array (`data` in the example code). It's handy to also include the table rows in that array, that saves some time when you don't have to query the DOM to find a row to highlight. Then create some variables to store some information of the state of the task (`current`, `next`). This information is used to control the state. Finally, create a timer, which runs when ever there's a next date to await. Calculate the delay based on the values you've stored in the model. Something like this:

```js
// Fill the dates (for the example only)
const rows = Array.from(document.querySelector('#traced').rows);
fillDates(new Date(), 5); // constant 5 = increase time [second]
// A date can be passed to Date constructor as an acceptable string too

// Creates the timer
(function() {
  const tbody = document.querySelector('#traced'),
    rows = Array.from(tbody.rows),
    data = rows.map(row => {
      const time = new Date(row.cells[1].textContent).getTime();
      // The constant 1 above is the date column number of the table
      return {row, time};
    });

  let now = Date.now(),
    last = data.length - 1,
    next = data.findIndex(row => row.time > now),
    current = Math.max(-1, next - 1);

  if (now > data[last].time) {
    // All the dates are in the past, no need for a timer
    data[last].row.classList.add('active');
    return;
  }

  // Updates row highlighting and counters, the timed function
  function activateRow() {
    // Update highlights
    if (current > 0) {
      // Remove the current highlight
      data[current - 1].row.classList.remove('active');
    }
    if (current > -1 && next) {
      // Highlight the current row
      data[current].row.classList.add('active');
    }
    // Set the timer if needed
    if (next > last) {return;} // Quit, no more dates to await
    const delay = data[next].time - Date.now();
    window.setTimeout(activateRow, delay);
    // Update counters
    current += 1;
    next += 1;
  }

  activateRow();
}());

// Emulates the server-side dynamic table filling (for the example only)
function fillDates(base, gap = 15000) {
  if (gap < 1000) {
    gap *= 1000;
  }
  gap += Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);
  const zone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
    date = new Date(base).getTime() - zone * 60000;
  rows.forEach((row, index) => {
    const dte = new Date(date + gap * index).toISOString(),
      end = dte.length - 5;
    row.lastElementChild.textContent = dte.substring(0, end);
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="traced">
    <tr><td>Date 1</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date 2</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date 3</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date 4</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date 5</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date 6</td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When you're integrating the example to your own code, include only the IIFE to your JS code, the other parts of the snippet are there to make it possible to run the code reasonably in StackSnippet nevertheless visitor's timezone. Of course you've to define `active` class in your CSS too. You should also not include the style of the active row on the server, the JS snippet takes care of the highlighting.

Depending on the date format in the table, you might also need to edit the code according to the used format, and even make changes to the actual dates, because depending on visitor's timezone, the dates you add on the server could be badly off on some other timezone, and the automatic highlighter won't work.

There's also [a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqzrx9h4/1/) to play with.

Comment: seems exactly as what I need thank you very much @Teemu, however, I couldn't make it run in my Vue component. I added your IIFE function in mounted() in vue but unfortunately, it is still not working! I am on it!

Comment: It doesn't have to be an IIFE, you can make it a declared function, or add the function as a method into an object or assign it to a variable etc., just don't forget to call it. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with vue, so I can't help you with the integration.

Comment: In this case, there would be many currents and many futures and pasts! for each group

Comment: @Abood If I've understood your description correctly, (the table is not ordered by the dates), you could sort `data` array by the dates in JS after it's been populated. Something like `data.sort((a, b) => return a.time - b.time)`.

Comment: thank you very much @Teemu I could get it working in Vue where I just define a method with your code and I call it in updated. I try to change also the logic behind the order, you assumed that future in lower rows but it is actually in the upper ones so I changed last to be 0 and `current = Math.max(0, next + 1);` but it didn't work as expected. Also, I still have a question, the data is ordered by date but not in general, I mean it is firstly grouped by other column then ordered by date.. so do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Abood Sorting the array should tackle both the problems you're facing, without changing the calculation for `current`.

Comment: I thought I solved the first part to have descending order to the dates but still, something missed the results are not as expected. I was wrong in my previous comment!

Comment: on I will try sorting solution, thanks for the idea

Comment: @Abood It looks like my suggestion [would work](https://jsfiddle.net/sof4yk3L/) (updated the link).

Comment: yes, it is working perfectly now. Thank you @Teemu

Comment: @Abood You probably have noticed for now, why this question was received a bit poorly here at SO. For your future questions, always add important details, like the relevant HTML structure and the related libraries and frameworks to the question. Rather include too much information than too less. A full example of the table and `vue` added to the text or at least tagging with it would most likely have saved you from the downvotes, that would have make the meaning of "_in the methods_" and the included JS code more clear.

Comment: I see, thank you for the advice, this is my very first question so I need some time to get used to it and to know the game rules here. thanks for your tip :)

Comment: Hi @Teemu your sol is working perfectly. However, I implemented a search button that brings new data to the table without refreshing the page. the issue is when I search for new data which means new dates. I got 2 rows green, one is the right one and the other is saved from the previous data. if I do the search twice it will highlight 3 rows (and so on). I was trying to reset data on the call of the main function by `const tbody=null` but it isn't the right sol. another idea is to reset any css class on the call of activateRow function, have no idea how to do it!!

Comment: @Abood Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2jmsy7h9/). Notice the outer scope variable `timer`, with that a running timer will be cleared in case the table has been updated. Only you've to do, is to call `schedule` function at the start of your page and always after updating the table.

Comment: actually, the timer is taking the right values but the active class isn't removed when retrieving new data, I need to remove all classes at the beginning of the schedule function call, is there a way to do that? remove active class if existed for any row before setting new setTimeout function? @Teemu

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add the line `row.classList.remove('active');` to the row mapping at the begininnig of the function, [a fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxv1qboL/).

Comment: yes now it is perfect. thank you so much @Teemu